# f is not continuous at any point c of its domain R when the metric d on R is Euclidean

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f\colon (\mathbb{R},d) \to (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot| )$ be defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\phantom{-}1, &x ∈ \mathbb{Q} \\-1, &x ∉ \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

I want to prove that $f$ IS NOT continuous at any point $c$ of its domain $\mathbb{R}$ when the metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is Euclidean .

I want to prove that $f$ IS continuous at all points of its domain when the metric $d$ is the discrete metric.

I know: A function $f$ is called continuous at $x \in X$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $ρ(f(y), f(x)) < \varepsilon$ whenever $d(y,x) < \delta$.

AND

I know alternatively: $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous iff whenever $x_n \to x$ in $X$ we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$

Comment: For the discrete metric $d(y,x)<1$ implies $y=x$ so $\rho (f(y),f(y))=0<\epsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second characterisation of continuity (called *sequentially continuous*) is the practical one in this case (and in the case of metric spaces, equivalent to continuity).

1) You want to prove that for a given $c\in \mathbb{R}$ the map $f$ is not continous at $c$. Let's assume that $c\in \mathbb{Q}$, so $f(c)=1$. So you want to find a sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which converges to $c$ in the euclidean metric such that $f(x_n)=-1$ for all $n$. This would show that $f$ is not continous at $c$. Such a sequence exists, $f(x_n)=-1$ means that $x_n \notin \mathbb{Q}$ . Can you find a sequence in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ which converges to $c\in \mathbb{Q}$? The case $c\notin \mathbb{Q}$ is analogous.

2) To show that $f$ is continous for $d=\text{discrete}$, you have to understand first, what $x_n \to c$ means in the discrete metric. A sequence $x_n$ converges to $c$ if $d(x_n,c) \to 0$. But the distance in the discrete metric of nonequal points is always $1$. What does that mean for your sequence?

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$ and so is $\Bbb R -\Bbb Q$. Hence for every real number $r$ there exist sequences $(a_k) \subset \Bbb Q$ and $(b_k) \subset \Bbb R - \Bbb Q$ such that $a_k \to r$ and $(b_k)\to r$. But $f(a_k)\to 1$  and $f(b_k)\to-1$. Hence f is not continuous. This answers your first question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use your last characterization and the sequence

$$x_n = c + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} \qquad y_n=c+\frac{1}{n}$$

May be useful separate cases when $c$ is or not rational.